Given application, grant, and publication numbers, containing duplicates of the same patent, how do I figure out the total number of unique patents?
How can I input a list of application numbers, grant numbers, and publication numbers, some of which may be duplicates of the same patent, and determine which ones correspond to the unique patent so I can count how many patents there are in my list?
What's a tool that will input a list and output for each input whether that given number is a publication number, application number, or grant number?
I'd try to figure this out for free.
I'd rather not buy something that isn't much better than pooling lens.org, patentscope, espacenet...
If it's going to cost $10,000 I might as well as a IP lawyer.
How do I avoid double counting without hiring a team of people or buying software to cross check redundancies?

Not sure I understand what you are looking for. On the lens, you can search by document type. How many documents are you dealing with?
